How to have 5 different always-on-top notes, one on each screen?
Screen as in the different desktops in mac os
I'm using macOS and I frequently work with multiple spaces. I'm looking for a way to have 5 different notes or quick notes that are always on top of all my other windows, with one note on each of my spaces. I want to be able to quickly jot down information or refer to important notes without having to switch between windows, applications, or spaces.
Ideally, the solution should have the following features:

Each note should be always on top, so it remains visible even when I'm working on other windows or applications within the same space.
I should be able to position one note on each of my spaces.
The notes should be easily accessible and allow me to quickly input or view information.
It would be great if the notes support basic formatting like bold, italic, and lists.
The ability to save and load notes would be a plus.

I'm open to using any software or tools that can achieve this functionality. It could be a dedicated note-taking application, a customizable widget, or even a combination of different tools.
I'm using the latest version of macOS.
If anyone has any suggestions, recommendations, or step-by-step instructions on how to set this up, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you in advance!

Havent used a Mac in many years, so dont know.  While not useful to the OP, this is trivial on Windows.  Just install MS PowerToys and you can set any window to be always on top with wIn+ctrl+T.  Hope you find an answer OP.

Wouldn’t you be better off asking this on the stack exchange website for Mac questions ? https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Can the staff move this question already

@Maslie OP placed a bounty on it. Until the bounty expires we cant migrate it.

@Mokubai Oh well that an issue for OP now. It would be better on the apple stackexhchange but we must wait

How sad, OP has lost 100 reps for nothing. Unless he/she wants to accept the only answer below right now?

To achieve this functionality on macOS, you have a few options, including using dedicated note-taking applications, floating widgets, or combination of tools. Here's a step-by-step guide using some of the best available tools:
Option 1: Using Stickies and a Third-Party Tool
Stickies is a built-in application on macOS that allows you to create floating notes. To ensure these notes stay on top, you can use a third-party tool like Afloat
Step-by-Step Instructions:

Open Stickies:

Open the Stickies app from the Applications folder or by searching for it in Spotlight.


Create and Position Notes:

Create five different Stickies notes and position each one in a separate space. You can move to different spaces using the Mission Control feature (usually triggered by swiping up with three or four fingers on the trackpad or pressing the Mission Control key).


Install Afloat:

Download and install Afloat. Note that Afloat is an older tool and might require some additional steps to work on the latest macOS versions, like using mySIMBL.
Alternatively, you can use Hammerspoon with a specific configuration to achieve a similar result.


Configure Notes to Stay on Top:

For Afloat, once installed, open the Stickies note, then go to the menu bar and select Window > Keep Afloat.
For Hammerspoon, use the following script to keep Stickies on top:
hs.hotkey.bind({"cmd", "alt", "ctrl"}, "T", function()
    local win = hs.window.focusedWindow()
    if win then
        win:setTopLeft(hs.mouse.getAbsolutePosition())
        win:setFrame(win:frame(), 0)
        win:setFrame(win:frame(), 1)
    end
end)





Option 2: Using Notion and Magnet (or another window management tool)
Notion is a powerful note-taking app that supports basic formatting and can be used with a window management tool like Magnet.
Step-by-Step Instructions:

Install Notion:

Download and install Notion from the Notion website.


Create Notes in Notion:

Create five separate pages or notes in Notion for your different spaces.


Install Magnet:

Download and install Magnet from the Mac App Store or another window management tool that allows you to keep windows in specific positions.


Position Notes:

Open each Notion note in a separate window and use Magnet to position each note in a specific space. Use Magnet's features to keep the windows on top if available.



Option 3: Using Floating Widgets
GeekTool allows you to create customizable widgets on your desktop.
Step-by-Step Instructions:

Install GeekTool:

Download and install GeekTool from the GeekTool website.


Create Widgets:

Use GeekTool to create five different text widgets on your desktop. You can customize the appearance and position of these widgets.


Position Widgets in Spaces:

Position each widget in a separate space using Mission Control.



Conclusion
Each of these options has its strengths, so you can choose the one that best fits your workflow. If you need basic formatting and a robust note-taking experience, Notion with a window manager like Magnet might be the best choice. If you prefer a lightweight and straightforward solution, Stickies with Afloat or Hammerspoon is a good option. For highly customizable desktop widgets, GeekTool is ideal.

afloat doesn't work

This looks like genAI to me

It's the most obvious ChatGPT ever, yet mods rejected the report.
